# how to customize regex pattern in pyspark

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have implemented a regex patterns to filter specific characters from text in jupyter notebook

now i trying to implement the same using regextokenizer in pyspark, Can one of you provide me inputs in customizing the regex in pyspark

```
    cleaned = re.sub('\W+', ' ', i).lower()
    # remove all single characters
cleaned = re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', cleaned)

# Remove single characters from the start
cleaned = re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', cleaned) 

# Substituting multiple spaces with single space
cleaned= re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', cleaned, flags=re.I)

# Removing prefixed 'b'
cleaned = re.sub(r'^b\s+', '', cleaned)
cleaned = cleaned.strip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing fancy here. With your Spark dataframe, create a new column based on the conditions you want and chain together as many Regex as you want (though it looks like your Regex could be much improved)

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lower, regexp_replace

df = df.withColumn(
    "cleaned",
    lower(col("raw")).regexp_replace(col("raw"), "\W+", " ")
)
```

Comment: The `functions` module also has `trim` for removing whitespace

Comment: Thank you @Morgan , i modified my code  and it worked

Comment: Happy to help! If the question is resolved, feel free to accept the answer so that others know when they go searching

Comment: I did now,. new to stack overflow , getting used to it